# Car race application to use as a demonstration

Tags: windows, windows-8, game

I'm looking for a program like a car race for demonstration purpose. It should be kind of a game but it's enough if the user can drive on a given road without competitors. There is no need for goals to achieve or different levels.

Normal race games have a menu where the user has to select its race mode etc but the application I'm looking for starts right in the game without such a menu. Also, in normal games the game is over when the computer competitors finished the race and the user is taken back to the menu but the application I'm looking for never quits and runs forever.

Since this should be for demonstration purpose, the graphics should be at least "okay". Is there kind of such a program? Or is there a SDK or something to build such a program without lots of programming? (The demonstration purpose is not about the program itself but about the joystick HID emulator.)

thanks!

edit: It must be a windows application and will run on windows 8 :)